# Common root CA with multiple intermediate CA on different server

Tags: openssl

I have a root CA(CA) and 2 intermediate(ICA1 & ICA2) CA's(generated using the root CA) running on different servers.

Using ICA1, generated a server cert(for server S1) and 2 user cert(for user U1 & U2).

Now, user certs is distributed to the user-U1 & U2(including chain trust ICA1 & CA) and they are able to successfully connect to S1.

Similarly using ICA2, generated a server cert(for server S2) and 2 user cert(for user U3 & U4).

Now, user certs is distributed to the user-U3 & U4(including chain trust ICA2 & CA) and they are able to successfully connect to S2.

Since the chain trust is distributed and both have same root CA. User - U1, U2 can connect to S2 and User - U3, U4 can connect to S1.

Now if I need to revoke access to U1, I can add him part of CRL in server that is running ICA1 and get his access revoked for server -S1.

How do I revoke him part of ICA2 as that is running in different server?

Comment: Can't you use the root CRL to achieve this? Or add the other Certs thumbprint to the other intermediate CRL?

Comment: I can definitely add other certs thumbprints. What is the other option?..Can't you use the root CRL to achieve this?..Can you explain on this?

Comment: There is a difference between revoking a certificate (which is reflected in a CRL or can be queried with OCSP - and which will be used if the certificate is compromised) and revoking access for a specific certificate (certificate still valid, but access denied to specific resources). The first one is relevant for PKI (certificate hierarchies), the second one not. Which of these revocations you are asking about?

Comment: Im more interested in revoking a certificate that is reflected in a CRL.Since I have 2 intermediate CA's in 2 different servers. I would like to know how to propagate the CRL changes from one CA to another.

Comment: @user1050619: there is no propagation of changes. You simply must provide the CRL on all places where they are needed, i.e. if server 2 should check the CRL for both ICA1 and ICA2 then it must have both CRL.